# Wrong Reachability status -Boolean value is not set in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, boolean

I have a `Boolean` value to check `Reachability` with following code.

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isOnline;



[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];

    Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Reachable");
            self.isOnline = YES;
        });
    };

    reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.isOnline = NO;
            NSLog(@"Unable");
        });
    };

    [reach startNotifier];
```

However when i check it with

```
if(self.isOnline == YES)
    {
NSLog(@"YES");
}

else{
NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

It's only showing NO. I am sure `Reachability` can reach to the internet and i have connection. However `Boolean` value is not set to `YES`.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) by Tony Million so 1st thing i would suggest is to use `isReachable` function in it.

Secondly, **there is an issue with this reachability in iOS7** so to resolve this you have to do the following

In the Function `-(BOOL)isReachableWithFlags:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)flags` in [Reachability.m](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/blob/master/Reachability.m) you have to commit one line

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    if(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)
    {
       // We're on 3G.
       if(!self.reachableOnWWAN)
          {
          // We don't want to connect when on 3G.
          // Comment this line
           //connectionUP = NO;

         }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: thanks you bro. above Code you mean , i need to set comment connectionUp = NO;?

Comment: Yes comment that line and Welcome :)